# submitting my Lite app with link to Pro version

Tags: iphone, ios

For the first time, Im uploading my app for review. My app has both a Lite and Pro version. On the Lite version I have a button to get the Pro version using code something similar to this:

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL   URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/MyApp-Pro/id?????????"]];
```

When I submit my app I presume I will get an individual Id number for the Lite and Pro version. My question is, will I be able to submit the Lite version with a complete Pro version link all at the same time or do I have to wait for the pro version to be excepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest first upload  the Pro version and get it approved.

Once pro version is approved, upload the lite version so that you don't have to worry about this link.

If you have luck, your lite will get on appstore even you don't have pro version on app store. All it depends on **reviewer**.

Answer (score 2):

This is hard to answer. If Apple aprooves your Lite app first there is probably not a problem. (You can get the ID as soon as you add the app description to iTunes Connect so you don't need to upload to get the ID). But if apple approves the lite version first, maybe they will reject it because the link is incorrect. It is hard to make assumptions on what Apple will do here.

Comment: Thanks Guys for your help - sounds like its a case of trial and error. I think I will go with the idea of uploading the Pro Version first. Any ideas on how long approval is for apps ??